# Substitution or elimination when a chloroalkene reacts with NaOH in ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, elimination, halogens

NaOH + EtOH will eliminate the Cl atom forming a double bond. At least, that's what I think. 3 could also be a viable answer since the OH can also attack the said double bond (this is probably not correct) and cause an OH to be added forming the compound in 3.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of the subtle difference between different bases that are strong in water but may not be equally strong in other, less polar solvents. Alcoholic *potassium* hydroxide certainly does eliminate a proton from the substrate leading to product (4), but *sodium* hydroxide in ethanol is just a little weaker and uses nucleophilic substitution to form (1) instead.

Comment: Supporting data? Perhaps 4 less ring strain and conjugated double bond. This is a better to see the products and determine the mechanism than quess the mechanism and guess the products.